# Only show button if purchased Stripe

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, stripe-payments

So I'm trying to have my app where when a user purchases a course they see a view modules button because when they purchase the course an order gets created so I'm checking whether an order exists.

However, currently when a course gets purchased the view modules get shown on all courses but I want it to only show on the course that is purchased.

Here is what I have so far:

schema.rb

```
  create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "summary"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "trailer"
    t.integer "price"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_courses_on_slug", unique: true
  end

  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "course_id"
    t.float "total"
    t.index ["course_id"], name: "index_orders_on_course_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_orders_on_user_id"
  end
```

Not purchased

[image]

Purchased

[image: image #2]

email marketing has been purchased but they are both showing the "view modules" button.

Here's how I'm doing the buttons

```
<section class="flex justify-between px-6 py-4">
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <% if current_user.isAdmin? %>
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_course_path(course), class: "inline-block text-lg w-full text-center text-grey-dark hover:text-darker px-4 py-2 border-2 border-grey leading-none no-underline hover:border-2 hover:border-grey-dark" %>
      <% else %>
        <% if Order.exists? %>
          <%= link_to "View Modules", course, class: "block text-lg w-full text-center text-grey-dark hover:text-darker px-4 py-2 border-2 border-grey leading-none no-underline hover:border-2 hover:border-grey-dark" %>
        <% else %>
          <%= form_with(url: '/payments/create') do |f| %>
            <script
              src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
              data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
              data-image="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aurameir-courses/aurameir-logo.png"
              data-name="<%= course.title %>"
              data-description="<%= course.summary %>"
              data-amount="<%= course.price*100 %>"
              data-label="Buy Now"
              >
            </script>
            <%= hidden_field_tag(:course_id, course.id) %>

            <%= f.submit "Buy now", class: "bg-blue hover:bg-blue-dark w-full text-white font-semibold py-3 px-4 border-2 rounded-sm border-blue-dark shadow outline-none" %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to "View", course, class: "block text-lg text-grey-dark hover:text-darker px-4 py-2 border-2 border-grey leading-none no-underline hover:border-2 hover:border-grey-dark" %>
      <span class="inline-block bg-green font-bold text-xl text-white border-2 border-green-dark px-4 py-2 leading-none shadow">£<%= course.price %></span>
    <% end %>
  </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
if Order.exists?
```

will check if *any* order exists. i.e. it will be true as long as there is at least one record in the orders table. However, you want to check for a *specific* order i.e. has the current user ordered a particular course. So you can replace this with:

```
if Order.exists?(user: current_user, course: course)
```

However this will run a separate query to check for the existence of an order for each course. Once you have more than a couple of courses this will become inefficient. So it would best to run a single query to find all the course IDs ordered by the current user and to then check against that list.

Comment: You could also do it as `current_user.orders.where(course: course).exists?` if you want it to read a little more ruby-ish